# Entry and Exit based on the Engulfing candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am writing a Pine Script to back test a custom strategy. But, it is not working as expected.

Expected is as per the strategy below.

**Strategy:**
**Long**

1. LTP should be above EMA 200.
2. RSI divergence should be more than 50
3. Previous candle should be Bullish Engulfing candle

**Exit**

1. Profit should be 4 times the size of the Engulfing candle
2. Stop loss should be 2 times the Engulfing candle

Following is the code I have written

```
//@version=5
strategy("Bullish scalping")

ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 9)
bullishEngulfing = open[1] > close[1] ? close > open ? close >= open[1] ? close[1] >= open ? close - open > open[1] - close[1] ? true :false :false : false : false : false

BUY_VALUE = 0
DIFF = 0

global = array.new_float(2)

buy = ((close > ema200) and (rsi > 50) and bullishEngulfing)

if( buy == true )
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 20.0)
    array.set(global,BUY_VALUE,close)
    array.set(global,DIFF,(close[1]-open[1]))

if ((close - array.get(global,BUY_VALUE) >= (array.get(global,DIFF)*4)) or (array.get(global,BUY_VALUE) - close >= (array.get(global,DIFF)*2)))
    strategy.close("Long")
```

The entry points are correct, but the exit points are not correct.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "But, it is not working as expected.". What do you expect and how is it working at the moment? Hard to help without knowing more details.

Comment: Maybe define these terms towards the bottom of the question. Stack overflow doesn't have to much of a financial focus and all these terms and acronyms are pretty unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use arrays for this. Also, for stop loss and target, it is better to use the functionality in `strategy.exit()` which will work as intended for that purpose. The code is below:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Bullish scalping")

ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 9)
bullishEngulfing = open[1] > close[1] ? close > open ? close >= open[1] ? close[1] >= open ? close - open > open[1] - close[1] ? true :false :false : false : false : false

BUY_VALUE = 0.0
DIFF = 0.0
Stop = 0.0
Target = 0.0

global = array.new_float(2)

buy = ((close > ema200) and (rsi > 50) and bullishEngulfing)

if (buy)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 20.0)

if strategy.position_size > 0
    BUY_VALUE := strategy.position_avg_price
    DIFF := ta.valuewhen(buy, close[1]-open[1], 0)
    Stop := BUY_VALUE - (DIFF * 2)
    Target := BUY_VALUE + (DIFF * 4)

    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", limit=Target, stop=Stop)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of few of the functions used here. Maybe I should look at the documentation first.